# Password shows when field is selected and hidden when not

Tags: html

I have a form on http://www.portal.codeclimb.com which is using the bootstrap framework.

I set my form type equal to "password" and it words (somewhat). The password will be hidden if there is absolutely nothing entered into the email address field. If you enter something into the email address field the password will still be hidden, but this is only when the field is not selected.

If there is text in the email field and you select the password field and start typing it displays the password once you un-select it, it then becomes hidden again.

Any idea on what could be going on?

```
<div class="form-group">
                <label for="managerEmail">Email Address</label>
                <div class="input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="icon-envelope"></i></span>
                    <input type="email" name="managerEmail" id="managerEmail" class="form-control">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="password">Account Password</label>
                <div class="input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="icon-lock"></i></span>
                    <input type="password" name="password" id="password" class="form-control">
                </div>
```

Comment: Where are the codes to control the show and hide of the password field?

Comment: @DanielCheng what codes to control it? It should just be the field in the html correct? type="password" should do it?

Comment: Cannot reproduce your problem, I think it must be something else other than the codes you posted.

Comment: What browser you are using? Mobile browsers handle password field differently.

Comment: It works for me in Chrome and Firefox. Of course IE doesn't work.... no surprises there. Can you add a link to a jsfiddle of your problem?